# with a bill of particulars that stretches right to the rug in front of Putin’s desk - what does this mean?

Tags: meaning

Source: http://www.businessinsider.com/this-is-what-kremlin-panic-looks-like-2014-7

> That would all work if it were 1975. But it’s not. I suspect the investigation, the tick-tock of the moments before the BUK fire, are already clear enough and widely distributed enough that we have the complete case against the “separatists” **with a bill of particulars that stretches right to the rug in front of Putin’s desk**.

I can't make sense of it. What is a bill of particulars and why does it stretch right to the rug that's in front of Putin's desk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Bill of particulars* is a legal term, defined at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_particulars) as

> ... a detailed, formal, written statement of charges or claims by a plaintiff or the prosecutor given upon the defendant's formal request to the court for more detailed information.

In other words, it is an explicit list (bill) of the specific charges or complaints (particulars) against a defendant in a criminal or civil court.

The author says that what we already know is enough to bring a detailed charge against the separatists, and that the list of specifics is long enough (metaphorically) to reach all the way to Putin’s office. An order must have been issued to someone standing (metaphorically) on “the rug in front of Putin’s desk”—that is, Putin himself must have given the order.

Answer (score 1):

A bill of particulars is a formal, written list of all the charges being brought against a defendant in a court case.

What the writer is saying by stating (metaphorically) that it 'stretches right to the rug in front of Putin's desk' is that the general consensus is that Russia, and by extension Putin, is to blame for the issue at hand.